# Identify what source was used in ORACLE COALESCE

Tags: sql, oracle, function, coalesce

How do I identify which source the COALESCE has returned data for?

I want something like:

```
SELECT    
COALESCE(SOURCE1, SOURCE2) SOURCE,
SOURCE_LOACTION
FROM
DATATABLE1 D1, DATATABLE2 D2
```

Where I have a column in the results displaying what source the data come from

**Answer:**

As I did my usual and didn't word my question well enough so I had to make up what I needed out of what everyone provided:

```
-- I was using COALESCE on more than one field
COALESCE(D1.FIELD1, D2.FIELD1) FIELD1,
COALESCE(D1.FIELD2, D2.FIELD2) FIELD2,
COALESCE(D1.FIELD3, D2.FIELD3) FIELD3,

CASE WHEN 

    D1.FIELD1 IS NULL AND
    D1.FIELD2 IS NULL AND
    D1.FIELD3 IS NULL AND

THEN 'SOURCE2' ELSE 'SOURCE1' END AS DATASOURCE
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT    
COALESCE(SOURCE1, SOURCE2) SOURCE,
,COALESCE(nvl2(source1,'source1',null), nvl2(source2,'source2',null)), 
FROM DATATABLE1 D1, DATATABLE2 D2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 id, 'a' source1, null source2 from dual union all
                     select 2 id, null source1, null source2 from dual union all
                     select 3 id, 'a' source1, 'b' source2 from dual union all
                     select 4 id, null source1, 'b' source2 from dual)
select id,
       coalesce(source1, source2) source,
       case when source1 is not null then 'source1' 
            else 'source2'
       end source_location1,
       case when source1 is not null then 'source1'
            when source2 is not null then 'source2'
       end source_location2
from   sample_data;


        ID SOURCE SOURCE_LOCATION1 SOURCE_LOCATION2
---------- ------ ---------------- ----------------
         1 a      source1          source1         
         2        source2                          
         3 a      source1          source1         
         4 b      source2          source2
```

N.B. I've included two ways of handling the case when both source1 and source2 are null; which one you pick depends on what you want displaying when both sources are null - null or the last source mentioned in the coalesce list.